# how to show external media in template in django

Tags: html, django, image

Hi i'm currently new to Django and i'm trying to populate a product page.

I'm having problem with  the img to show the image(which uses an image url online instead of a file) for example an img `src="media3.scdn.vn/img2/2018/6_2/ZIBLXA_simg_b5529c_250x250_maxb.jpg"`

The url already in my database with the text `media3.scdn.vn/img2/2018/6_2/ZIBLXA_simg_b5529c_250x250_maxb.jpg`

But when i tried to render it in template the image doesn't show
I tried to used the  but it still not work
Any help would be appreciate!

My template

```
{% for discount in discounts|slice:":8" %}
    <div class="col-md-3 product-men women_two">
        <div class="product-googles-info googles">
            <div class="men-pro-item">
                <div class="men-thumb-item">
                    <img src="{{STATIC_URL}}{{discount.product_image}}" alt="" />
                    <div class="men-cart-pro">
                        <div class="inner-men-cart-pro">
                            <a href="single .html" class="link-product-add-cart">Quick View</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <span class="product-new-top">New</span>
                </div>
                <div class="item-info-product">
                    <div class="info-product-price">
                        <div class="grid_meta">
                            <div class="product_price">
                                <h4>
                                    <a href="single.html">{{discount.product_name}}</a>
                                </h4>
                                <div class="grid-price mt-2">
                                    <span class="money">{{discount.product_old_price}}</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <h3>{{discount.product_sit}}</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div><h2 style="color: red;">Only {{discount.product_price}}!</h2></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

**EDIT**

Seems like the image src trying to get is "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media3.scdn.vn/img2/2018/6_2/ZIBLXA_simg_b5529c_250x250_maxb.jpg" which i don't want "http://127.0.0.1:8000/" in the link. Is there a way to remove this  when using {{discount.product_image}} tag ?

Main project urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('frontend.urls')),
]
```

frontend app urls.py:

```
from  django.urls import path
from .import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
app_name = 'frontend'
urlpatterns = [
    #index
    path('',views.index, name='index')
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `.url` like this.

```
<img src="{{ discount.product_image.url }}"  alt=""/>
```

Also add the `MEDIA` and `STATIC` url to your project url patterns.

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URL pattern goes here ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) \
+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

**EDIT:**

From the discussion in chat, I understood that I had misunderstood your problem first. The images are external and not in your db, you are just storing the URL to the images. And you are using a `TextField` not `ImageField`. I assumed `ImageField` previously. So, all you have to do is to replace `{{STATIC_URL}}` from in front of the actual URL and put `http://` there. The reason behind this is, as the `src` is missing `http://` it's assumed the image to be in the same host domain. So it goes to `http://127.0.0.1/your_url`.

```
<img src="http://{{ discount.product_image }}"  alt=""/>
```

Comment: it still doesn't work . It came back with "[13/Nov/2018 13:53:49] "GET /media3.scdn.vn/img2/2018/6_8/3eJ0YO_simg_b5529c_250x250_maxb.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 2290" it seem to created a "/" before the url which make the link the the url wrong

Comment: Also, make sure you have set `MEDIA_URL`, `MEDIA_ROOT` `STATIC_URL`, `STATIC_ROOT` correctly.

Comment: now the other url for the website(main page) won't work File "C:\Users\admin\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\django-2.1-py3.6.egg\django\conf\urls\static.py", line 21, in static
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Empty static prefix not permitted")
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Empty static prefix not permitted

Comment: You haven't set `STATIC_URL` and `STATIC_ROOT` properly.

Comment: My website has different apps in it so should i set it in the main url or on other urls of each app too ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183527/discussion-between-md-khairul-basar-and-zerontelli).